# Write to NSLog and file PythonObjC

Tags: python, file-io, pyobjc

I'm trying to modify a script to additionally print to a log file. It already uses `NSLog()`. I'm definitely still learning Python... Anyways, here's what I have so far:

```
# cocoa_keypress_monitor.py by Bjarte Johansen is licensed under a 
# License: http://ljos.mit-license.org/

from AppKit import NSApplication, NSApp
from Foundation import NSObject, NSLog
from Cocoa import NSEvent, NSKeyDownMask
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
import sys

class AppDelegate(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
        mask = NSKeyDownMask
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(mask, handler)

def handler(event):
    try:
        NSLog(u"%@", event)
        with open("/Users/Zachary/Downloads/foo.txt", "a", 0) as myfile:
            myfile.write(u"%@", event)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

def main():
    app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    delegate = AppDelegate.alloc().init()
    NSApp().setDelegate_(delegate)
    AppHelper.runEventLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I attempted to pass `myfile.write()` the same data as `NSLog()`, but Python doesn't like that and I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to [`file.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) is not [a format string like `NSLog()`'s argument](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html), it's just a single regular string. You need to coerce the `NSEvent` object to be a string, by passing it to Python's `str()` function. (PyObjC knows to call an Objective-C object's `-description` method, as `NSLog()` does, in that situation.)

You should also note that `%@` is not a valid [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for Python format strings: it is only used in ObjC. Actually, the preferred format string syntax in Python now doesn't even use percent escapes. If you wanted to format the `NSEvent` into a Python string explicitly, you would do something like: `"{}".format(event)`